# Stream the sound of pure data in an FM station on a Raspberry Pi with the PiFmRds library

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, puredata

I'm trying to stream the sound from a Raspberry Pi of an [SPH0645](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Knowles%20Acoustics%20PDFs/SPH0645LM4H-B.pdf) microphone in [FM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency_modulation) with the PiFmRds library.

Here's what I've tried:

After the installation of the microphone, here's what I have:

```
arecord -l
```

Output

```
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 1: sndrpii2scard [snd_rpi_i2s_card], device 0: simple-card_codec_link snd-soc-dummy-dai-0 [simple-card_codec_link snd-soc-dummy-dai-0]
```

Then I can record normally without any problems with this command:

```
arecord -D plughw:0 -c1 -r 48000 -f S32_LE -t wav -V mono -v file.wav
```

I can stream the file:

```
sox -t mp3 /home/thib/file.wav -t wav - | sudo /home/thib/PiFmRds/src/pi_fm_rds -audio -
```

But here is my problem: I would like stream the direct output of my microphone. For that I've tried:

```
sudo arecord -D plughw:1 -c1 -r 48000 -f S32_LE -t wav  | sudo ./pi_fm_rds -audio -
```

After that, I've tried to use the loopback function, but I don't have any sound in my receptor.

```
sudo modprobe snd-aloop
```

Output:

```
 arecord -l
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 1: sndrpii2scard [snd_rpi_i2s_card], device 0: simple-card_codec_link snd-soc-dummy-dai-0 [simple-card_codec_link snd-soc-dummy-dai-0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 3: Loopback [Loopback], device 0: Loopback PCM [Loopback PCM]
  Subdevices: 8/8
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
  Subdevice #1: subdevice #1
  Subdevice #2: subdevice #2
  Subdevice #3: subdevice #3
  Subdevice #4: subdevice #4
  Subdevice #5: subdevice #5
  Subdevice #6: subdevice #6
  Subdevice #7: subdevice #7
card 3: Loopback [Loopback], device 1: Loopback PCM [Loopback PCM]
  Subdevices: 8/8
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
  Subdevice #1: subdevice #1
  Subdevice #2: subdevice #2
  Subdevice #3: subdevice #3
  Subdevice #4: subdevice #4
  Subdevice #5: subdevice #5
  Subdevice #6: subdevice #6
  Subdevice #7: subdevice #7
```

```
sudo arecord -D plughw:3 -c1 -r 48000 -f S32_LE -t wav  | sudo /home/thib/PiFmRds/src/pi_fm_rds
```

I've also tried to use a program like pure data but nothing change... How can I fix itg?

Comment: How is this on-topic for Stack Overflow?